# Force maven to built plugins before other modules

Tags: maven

In a multi-module project, which contains some maven plugins used by other normal modules, something like:

```
parent
|
 ---- maven-plugins
      |
       ---- plugin1
      |
       ---- plugin2
|
 ---- module1
|
 ---- module2
|
 ---- ...
|
 ---- moduleN
```

Is there any way to force Maven to build/install plugin artifacts before the others?

I mean, I'd like to avoid the step of manually installing the plugins before building the parent project. I tried to put it the first at the modules, but no result, the reactor plugin looks not to handle it.

Comment: I guess that's the case already. maven-plugins are built before your own project. If not then how would your code compile if that is dependent on the plugins.

Comment: I would suggest to remove the creation of plugins from your project and make them separate project to have better control over unit/integration testing etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is due to a bug in Maven:

[MNG-1911 - Building plugins with extensions in a reactor fails](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-1911)

You will need to build plugins outside the reactor first to make them available to the other modules.